# Javascript Array to Sentence

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I turn an array, such as `["Susy", "John", "Mary"]` to `"Susy, John, and Mary"` in Javascript? I can't get Ruby's to_sentence method out of my head.

Comment: not so seriously, but.. `["Susy", "John", "Mary"].join(',').split(/,M/).join(' and M');`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Join all items except the last one, and then add that:

```
var s = arr.slice(0, arr.length - 1).join(', ') + ", and " + arr.slice(-1);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JYKcK/1/

Comment: Just one note- Americans put a comma before the "and". OP has done this.

Comment: @popnoodles: Ah, then you would just use `+ ", and " +`.

Comment: I can see a couple of problems with this method.  If there's only 1 element in the array, it will return ", and Susy".  For two elements, it returns "Susy, and John", which isn't grammatically correct.

Comment: @Alex: Yes, with less that three items you need additional code, but that's outside the scope of the question. There is no answer here that handles that case.

Comment: Good point, but I think if you're only concerned with the specific use case presented, you could end up with something like jAndy's (joke) answer :-) I've posted an answer that covers the most obvious cases I could think of.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: A very interesting piece of code but it will fail if we have an array of one element. it will print the only element after the `and`.

Comment: a solution to @Alex 's case is `arr.length > 2 ? arr.slice(0, arr.length - 1).join(', ') + ", and " + arr.slice(-1) : arr.length == 2 ? arr.join(' and ') : arr.length == 1 ? arr[0] : ""`

Answer (score 22):

Using newest JavaScript (Chrome 72+):

```
new Intl.ListFormat().format(["Susy", "John", "Mary"]);
```

which will result in:

```
"Susy, John, and Mary"
```

Comment: Whoa, this is going to be great, when it's supported! https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/12/intl-listformat

Comment: Awesome! But unfortunately still poorly supported by other browsers :( https://caniuse.com/#search=ListFormat

Answer (score 11):

Another option, using `Array.prototype.reduce`, would be:

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
arr.reduce(
  function(prev, curr, i){ 
    return prev + curr + ((i===arr.length-2) ? ' and ' : ', ')
  }, '')
.slice(0, -2);
```

Produces `"1, 2 and 3"`.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few extra cases in this one:

1. Do we want to have a comma before the "and" (Oxford Comma)
2. Either way, we don't want a comma if there are only 2 elements
3. If there is only 1 element, we just want that word returned

I think this fits all of those use cases:

```
function joinSentence( array, oxford_comma ){
  if( array.length > 1 ){
    var lastWord = " and " + array.pop();
    if( oxford_comma && array.length > 1 ){
      lastWord = "," + lastWord;
    }
  }else{
    var lastWord = "";
  }
  return array.join(", ") + lastWord;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
toSentence = function(arr){ return arr.join(", ").replace(/,\s([^,]+)$/, ' and $1');};

toSentence(['dogs', 'cats']);           // => dogs and cats

toSentence(['dogs', 'cats', 'snakes']); // => dogs, cats and snakes
```

Answer (score 3):

And another solution:

```
(function(a) {
    var b = (a||(a=[])).pop(); 
    return (b ? a.length ? [a.join(", "),b] : [b] : a).join(" and ");
})(["Susy", "John", "Mary"]);
```

or just defining your ruby-like sentence method in array's prototype:

```
Array.prototype.sentence = function(comma,and) {
    var b = this.pop();
    return (b ? this.length ? [this.join(comma||", "),b] : [b] : this).join(and||" and ");
};

["Susy", "John", "Mary"].sentence(); 
//"Susy, John and Mary"

["Susy", "John", "Mary"].sentence(" and ", " as well as "); 
//"Susy and John as well as Mary"

["Susy", "John", "Mary", "Helmut"].sentence(); 
//"Susy, John, Mary and Helmut"
```

Answer (score 2):

modify the last then join

```
var source = ["Susy", "John", "Mary"];
source.push( 'and ' +source.pop());
console.log(source.join(', '))// Susy, John, and Mary
```

Comment: ok this is sexier :) But is it grammatically correct to add a comma before and?

Comment: Doesn't work for 1 and 2 elements: ["Susy"] => "and Susy". ["Susy", "John"] => "Susy, and John"

Answer (score 2):

Try that:

```
var array = ['susy', 'john', 'mary'];
var last = array.pop();
var string = array.join(', ') + " and " + last;
```

i didn t try but you should get the idea

Answer (score 1):

You can use .join() and prepend the last value with an "and"

```
var array = ['susy', 'john', 'mary'];

array[array.length-1] = 'and '+array[array.length-1];

//string is "susy, john, and mary"
var string = array.join(', ');
```

Comment: I know of this method, I'm wanting "and" before the last item.

Comment: my bad, I didn't see the "and"... let me re-factor

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to do it:

```js
function toSentence(array) {
  const lastWord = (array.length > 1) ? ` and ${array.pop()}` : ''
  return array.join(', ') + lastWord
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is actually an easier way these days, just use method `join();`
For example, `let array = ["Susy", "John", "Mary"];`
`array.join();` This will return `Susy,John,Mary`

Answer (score -3):

```
var arr = ["Susy", "John", "Mary"];
var str = arr.join(", ");
```

Comment: This produces `"Susy, John, Mary"`, which is not the desired result.